# permission issues with service principal while encrypting Linux VM

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

As part of disk encryption for a Linux VM in Azure, I asked customer to create key vault and Service principal as I don’t have access to their AD though I have owner permissions of the subscription. I used that service principal to do the Linux VM disk encryption. I am ending up in getting permission issues.  I think the reason for this is, since I doesn’t have access to their AD, I doesn’t have enough permission to use service principal which is created by customer.

Now I am asking customer to do following actions:

Step-1: Grant the permissions
go to Azure Active Directory, go to App registrations, select All Apps, click on webapp which we created, click on settings, click on Required permissions, Click on Grant permissions and then Yes.

Step-2: Add me as the owner for service principal
Go to Azure Active Directory, go to App registrations, select All Apps, click on webapp which we created, click on settings, click on Owners and add me as the owner for the service principal by clicking on +Add owner. This should give access to use this service principal.

After these two steps, hope my issue will be resolved. I would like to take your opinion before asking customer. Please give your suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the AADClientID and Secret from the App that should be fine on the AAD side.

Make sure the you give the App permission to the Key Vault and enable the keyvault for Disk Encryption.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-disk-encryption#prerequisites